# How to add a custom security annotation to Spring MVC controller method

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, security

I am using Java 8, Spring MVC 4, Spring Boot, and Gradle for my REST application.

I would like to add security to my REST application via custom method annotations within certain Spring MVC 4 controllers.

Here is a basic example.

**HomeController.java**

```
package myapp;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "<h1>Hello, World!</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>";
    }

    @CustomSecurityAnnotation
    @RequestMapping("/secure")
    public String secure() {
        return "<h1>Secured!</h1><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>";
    }
}
```

I would like `CustomSecurityAnnotation` to run a custom method that will check the headers of the incoming REST request, look at HTTP header `Authorization`, pull the value provided (if one was provided), and run code against that value to validate the request **before** allowing the method to proceed. The annotation should have the ability to override the response and provide a HTTP 401 or 403 if the authorization is invalid, and allow the method under the annotation to run if I decide the annotation custom method passed successfully.

I realize there is something similar I could do with `PreAuthorize` and other MVC annotations but I'm looking at packaging up custom logic within a method inside a single annotation to be used on any method on any controller of my choosing.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please be more particular why the **PreAuthorize** is not eligible for your requirements? I can't catch up with your statements.

Comment: A simple customer filter will handle that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We also created a custom annotation in our project.
What you need to accomplish this, is a bit of Aspect Oriented Programming.

First you'll want to create your own annotation to tag your methods, as follows:

```
public @interface CustomSecurityAnnotation {
}
```

Then you have to write the logic which is triggered when your method is executed.
You write an **aspect** for that.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomSecurityAspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(my.package.CustomSecurityAnnotation)")
    private void customSecurityAnnotation() {
    }

    @Around("my.package.CustomSecurityAspect.customSecurityAnnotation()")
    public Object doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        HttpServletRequest req = getRequest();
        // Check header values
        // Throw Spring's AccessDeniedException if needed
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

    private HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        return sra.getRequest();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've already included a method to retrieve the current HTTP request so you can easily retrieve the header you want to check.

In case of an `AccessDeniedException`, Spring automatically sets the response status code to HTTP 403.

Don't forget to enable `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on your `@Configuration` class to enable aspects.

Comment: You can add extra attributes to your annotation if you want.
By using reflection in your aspect, you can decide what to do depending on an attribute's value.

Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html for more information.

Comment: So this is confirmed to be working! One small correct though, the @Around annotation needs to have "my.package.CustomSecurityAnnotation.customSecurityAnnotation()" instead of what you have. A minor issue. And for anyone else listening in. Here are some dependencies you'll need to include in your Gradle/Maven:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop

Overall works well! Thank you!

Comment: Some other developers are telling me that a Interceptor is a better route to go than using AOP. Do you have any comment on that?

Comment: First of all, ``HandlerInterceptor`` is part is the ``spring-web`` module, which you only need when you're using a server-side rendering technology, like for instance Thymeleaf. When you're building a REST API, you don't work with ``ModelAndView`` etc. On top of that, the way I see it, with an interceptor, you'll have to configure all your mappings in one configuration file, separate from your method. I think it's less manageable if you want methods to be excluded from your security check.

Comment: @KenCoenen could you please explain how do I add extra attribute using reflextion?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create your own Aspect (or you want to rely on plain Spring-Security), you can take the mechanisms of Spring Security and create your own custom `SecurityExpressionRoot` like shown here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression#2-custom-expression-handler

The wonderful part is you have the methodInvocation delivered by the framework, get your annotation via reflection and pass it to your `CustomSecurityExpressionRoot`. In Kotlin this looks like follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class MethodAuthConfig: GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration() {
override fun createExpressionHandler(): MethodSecurityExpressionHandler = object: DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
    override fun createSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication: Authentication, invocation: MethodInvocation): MethodSecurityExpressionOperations =
        SecuredTargetExpressionRoot(
            authentication,
            // This is the important part to find your own annotation and pass it to your method security resolver
            invocation.method.annotations.mapNotNull { it as? SecuredTarget }.firstOrNull()
        ).apply {
            setThis(invocation.getThis())
            setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator)
            setTrustResolver(trustResolver)
            setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy)
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing missing is to add an SpringSecurity annotation to your own annotation like:

```
@Target(FUNCTION)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
// This is the important line to let Spring security kick in action
@PreAuthorize("canAccessTarget()")
annotation class SecuredTarget (
    // maybe any variables your want to specify at this annotation
)
```

And to have a look in your custom SpEl for Spring-Security:

```
class SecuredTargetExpressionRoot(
    authentication: Authentication,
    private val securityInformation: SecuredTarget?
): SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication), MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
    fun canAccessTarget(): Boolean {
        return // Your code of verification goes here :)
    }
}
```

(I created this in my kotlin project. But I guess you have no problem converting these lines into Java-Code. Most of what you need to do is in the linked tutorial. I just point out where to get your custom Annotation information from ;) And on the plus side: You can use all of Spring-Securitys mechanism without having to write your own logic to catch exceptions etc.)